# Firebase / Google VR linker error in Unity - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an iOS app using unity (v2019.1.0f2) and firebase (v6.0) and Google VR (v1.200). When I use an empty project and add firebase, it would build successfully. If I clicked the Virtual Reality support, it import stuff then when I build. I face the following problem in Xcode

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRPhoneAuthCredential
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGameCenterAuthProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GKLocalPlayer
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRPhoneAuthProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROAuthProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRFacebookAuthProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIREmailAuthProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGoogleAuthProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGitHubAuthProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRTwitterAuthProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're missing the CocoaPods related to FirebaseAuthentication. There are a few things to check:

1. make sure you open the generated workspace (default settings) rather than the generated project:

[image: Screenshot with generate workspace selected in iOS Resolver Settings]
[image: Screenshot with iOS build output displayed - box around the xcworkspace file rather than the xcodeproj]

2. Next you'll want make sure that the `Podfile` exists in the build output directory and that it has the necessary pods. For my sample project with "Firebase Authentication" and "Firebase Realtime Database", my `Podfile` looks like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '6.24.0'
end
```

You can see which pod files you need [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=ios#libraries-ios), but the [External Dependency Manager for Unity (EDM4U)](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) should have handled this for you. So first I'd make sure that that's installed and configured.

Then I'd check to see if there is a `Podfile` at all. If there is, another extension may have overwritten the Firebase dependencies with their own. Ideally they'd use EDM4U (I wrote an article about that [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef)), but it would be up to you to either modify their process to pull in CocoaPod dependencies or to re-add Firebase's as part of your build process.

If there is no Podfile at all, you'll want to make sure that there's an "External Dependency Manager for Unity" package:

[image: External Dependency Manager for Unity]

or folder under the `Assets/` directory.

You'll also want to make sure that there aren't any build issues when you make an iOS build (they might not appear in normal stop/stop cycles in editor) and that you don't have a legacy "Play Services Resolver" folder.

You may also want to try manually installing CocoaPods via the EDM4U menu:

[image: Screenshot showing "Install Cocoapods" under "Assets/External Dependency Manager for Unity/iOS Resolver"]

Or to fully [uninstall](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-uninstall-CocoaPods) then reinstall cocoapods cocoapods if you recently migrated to MacOS Catalina.

I hope one of those solutions helps!

--Patrick